# "Less babies as they are having, there still increases the population."

Tags: as

Is it right to say like this sentence?

> Less babies as they are having, there still increases the population.

I mean

> Although they're having less babies, the population still increases.

Comment: Did you mean fewer babies?

Answer (score 3):

The first sentence is not correct.

Ignoring the first part, and stripping the adverb "still," the main clause

> There increases the population.

Is not an idiomatic way of saying

> The population increases.

There are only a few verbs in English which allow rephrasing to make "There" the first word of the sentence, and "to increase" is not one of them. Usually these verbs have to do with "existence, coming in to view, or being in a specific location" as @Araucaria says in [this ELU answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/313426/421933), which you can read for more information.

Finally, as "babies" is countable, "fewer" is preferred in place of less, and a continuous form for the verb "increase" would be more natural for a process that is ongoing.

> Although they're having fewer babies, the population is still increasing.

Comment: [There rises now a single tide of tourists passing through...](https://stanrogers.net/the-music/song-archive/fishermans-wharf/)

Comment: @randomhead 1. Song/Poem vs formal writing and/or common/accepted speech 2. Different context and use of "there"

Comment: @TCooper obviously a song lyric is not the same as standard English—I posted that as a joke—but I fail to see how "there" is used any differently than in OP's question?

Comment: *whoosh* that's the joke going over my head ;) But I would say my song lyric point is  moot in this case - let me get back to on why/how it's used differently. I don't have the correct vocab to describe it accurately off the top of my head - aaand you're making me research because I'll (always try at least to) be the first to acknowledge my mistakes - and you've made me uncertain.

Comment: @randomhead I've edited to address your point, even if was posted as a joke!  "There increases the population" may be acceptable in a folksy song about fishermen, but is isn't prosaic English.  It's not acceptable as a standard rephrasing of "The population increases".  This makes the OP's sentence borderline incomprehensible.  So I've added the word "prosaic" to my answer.

Comment: @TC I guess the question is what makes expressions like the term (from math) "there exists," which is good usage, and "there rises," which is borderline but acceptable, different from "there increases," which is not acceptable. Perhaps the problem is with the article? "There increases **a** population of [some specific people]" could work, or at least sounds not-as-wrong compared to "There increases **the** population." (But the verb has something to do with it as well... "there **a**rises a population" would be even better.)

Comment: @TC: https://english.stackexchange.com/q/313419/421933